# Como saber quando duas Threads terminaram em Swing?

Tags: java, swing, thread

Tenho um método que realiza duas tarefas. Gostaria que duas `threads` realizassem cada tarefa. As tarefas não compartilham dados, são totalmente independentes.

Antes de começar as tarefas é mostrado uma `dialog` com a informação "Aguarde, processando...".

Aqui estão os códigos:

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, true);
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // Faz trabalho
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
      // Devo fechar Dialog? O outro terminou?
   }
};

SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker2 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // Faz trabalho
      return null;
   }
   @Override
   protected void done() {
      //Devo fechar Dialog? O outro terminou?
   }
};

worker.execute();
worker2.execute();
dialog.setVisible(true);
// Devo fechar o dialog aqui?
```

As perguntas já estão comentadas no código.

Gostaria de fechar o `dialog` só quando as duas `threads` terminaram. Como saber o quando elas terminaram? Quem deve fechar o `dialog`?

Comment: Essa é fácil, é quando uma terceira Thread entra na jogada! /s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Crie um `CountDownLatch` iniciado em 2;
- Crie os dois `SwingWorkers`, passando a cada um o `CountDownLatch` como referência. Nos métodos `done()` de cada um chame o `countDown()` do *latch*. Faça isso nos métodos `done()`, já que serão chamados independendo de como o método `doInBackground()` terminar (no caso de lançar uma `Exception`);
- Crie um terceiro `SwingWorker`, passando como referência o `CountDownLatch`. Neste `worker` chame o método `await()` do *latch* no `doInBackground()`. No método `done()` desse `SwingWorker` pode fechar o `dialog` com segurança.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554386/how-to-know-when-two-threads-are-finished-in-swing

Answer (score 1):

Então, não sei se está é a melhor solução pois não mecho muito com swing.

Porém você precisa esperar as duas "thread" terminar para avisar o dialog.

```
   while( true ){
     if( worker.isDone() && worker2.isDone() )
     {
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        break;
     }
   }
```

Colocando isso após:

```
worker.execute();
worker2.execute();
```

Deve funcionar, porém como eu falei, não tenho certeza se essa é a melhor solução.
Espero ter ajudado.