# Multi processamento/Multithread não está a funcionar

Tags: java, swing, thread, multithreading

Quero tentar resolver o problema de quando o cliente não consegue se conectar com o servidor(falha de ligação, servidor em baixo, etc).

Na minha classe principal está a ligação ao servidor e eu quero que no caso de dar erro apanhado pelo `try ... catch(ConnectException ex)` lançar um `JDialog` a informar o cliente que ainda não está conectado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algo deste género, o JDialog é criado mas só é desenhado quando a operação acaba, isto é enquanto a thread principal tenta se conectar nao desenha nada, só quando consegue a conexão é que desenha tanto o JDialog como o frame principal.

Código para conectar ao server:

```
public Socket connect() {
    try {       

        this.socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    } catch (ConnectException ex) { 
                waitinng();//crio o frame mas ele só aparece quando o servidor está conectado
                System.out.println("tenta conectar");
                connect();//volto a chamar a função até que se consiga conectar
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return socket;
}
```

Para aparecer o JDialog já tentei:

Criar uma class normal, mas nao funcionou;

Criar uma thread que cria o JDialog, também não deu

Agora por ultimo estou a tentar com o swingworker, mas com alguns problemas...

Perguntas:

- O swingWorker é o caminho que devo seguir?
- O que devo inserir como parametros de entrada `SwingWorker<Integer,
  Integer>`
- É no doInBackground que devo criar o JDialog ou no construtor?

**EDIT**
Tenho serias duvidas se o meu problema está no multithread ou na maneira como o java processa o que quero fazer...

Esboço:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nao sei se ajuda esta edição...

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta mais ou menos sobre o mesmo assunto, veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38078/14674

Comment: O programa não está a cair em nenhuma exception ?

Comment: @AndréLizardo não, não está, o código está todo a funcionar, dentro `doInBackground` criei um ciclo for a fazer printf e esses printfs mostra na consola, mas o JDialog nao(só desenha no fim)

Comment: @Earendul pode se dizer que sim, mas o meu problema está um pouco antes do teu, como crias te o JDialog dentro da StringWorker? o meu grande problema é, se executar a JDialog sozinho ele funciona, mas se o chamo dentro do StringWorker o JDialog só fica visível depois do processo de conectar com o server que é quando a form do cliente aparece tambem...

Comment: Você pode responder sua própria pergunta com a solução que você encontrou, ;)

Comment: @Earendul muitas desculpas, o problema AINDA não está resolvido, continua exactamente igual, parecia mas enganei me

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com Thread, fiz um exemplo simples tem o JFrame a thread principal e um botão que quando você clica inicia outra Thread que exibe o jDialog você pode por esse seu código dentro do método run() e passar por referencia os Sockets, você precisa por todo código necessário para executar em paralelo, criar apenas o jDialog em uma Thread não vai funcionar

Classe Frame - Thread principal

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JButton botao;
    private JDialog dialog;

    public Frame() {

        botao = new JButton("OK");
        botao.addActionListener(new BotaoEvento());
        this.add(botao);
        botao.addActionListener(null);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public class BotaoEvento implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Dialog(dialog));
            thread.start();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Classe Dialog - Thread Extra

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class Dialog implements Runnable {

    JDialog dialog;

    public Dialog(JDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    public void run() {
        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setSize(200, 200);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        //operações que você deseja executar
    }

}
```